# DFS-R Only syncing one sub directory

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

We've got 11 servers running 2012 R2, configured with Active Directory and using DFS-R to sync Roaming profiles and general data in a folder called "Shared" over our VPN.

All of the servers are working perfectly - except one. Its syncing sysvol and the user profiles correctly, but the contents inside the "shared" folder are not.

The server was previously working, however it started to play up (wasn't syncing the folder at all), I tried removing and re-creating the DFSR config however couldn't get it working again so I decided to reload it.

Since the reload the server has only been syncing one folder. For example we've got folders A, B, C, D, E, F, G and its only syncing the data inside folder "F" nothing else. I've tried removing it from DFS-R and waiting for the 4010 event, deleting the "shared" folder and re-creating everything, however it just syncs the data inside "F". I've also tried creating empty text files, on the offending server, and then on another text file on a different server to see if it syncs - it doesn't.

I've checked the folder permissions to make sure that System has full access to the folders (which it does)..

I'm guessing its something to do with the DFSR database, but I'm guessing that you can't just delete information out of it for one member only?

Any suggestions?